# Get all attributes group of a specific resource model?

Tags: eav, resource-model, group

How I can get all attributes group name of a specific eav resource model?

Comment: please visit:-http://inchoo.net/magento/creating-an-eav-based-models-in-magento/  2)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559166/magento-how-to-get-attribute-values-used-in-products

Comment: I want to find all the names of groups of attributes , not all attributes.

Comment: And then I want to take the attributes in groups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the all attribute group by below code.

```
$entityType = 4; //catalog_product
$attributeSetTableWithPrefix = Mage::getSingleton("core/resource")->getTableName('eav_attribute_set');

$groups = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_group_collection');
$groups->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('attribute_set' => $attributeSetTableWithPrefix), 'main_table.attribute_set_id = attribute_set.attribute_set_id', array())
->where('attribute_set.entity_type_id = ?', 4);

$attributeGroup = array();
foreach($groups as $group){
    $attributeGroup[]= $group->getAttributeGroupName();
}
var_dump($attributeGroup);
```